# jqGrid editurl return value

Tags: jqgrid, jqgrid-php

I currently have a jqGrid that edits data in the database using editurl. How do I do actions after receiving a reply from the server, for example check if the updated succeeded, or a message returned by the server.

if there's no jqGrid function that does this, how then can I go about doing this?

Comment: Which editing mode you use: inline editing or form editing? All the editing modes has the corresponding events, but the name of the events and its parameters are different.

Comment: was using inline. fixed already tho. thx

Comment: Requesting to close the Question as this is Solved and no more answers are needed.

Answer (score 0):

The OP wrote:

> solved. API for edit row is as below.
>
> ```
> jQuery("#grid_id").jqGrid('editRow',rowid, keys, oneditfunc, succesfunc, url, extraparam, aftersavefunc,errorfunc, afterrestorefunc);
> ```
>
> Put the function you want under `aftersavefunc`, and take in 2 params, the row_id and the response. the response is a `XMLhttpRequest` Object.